# How to map Map<String,List<String>> ie..a nested collection in Hibernate using annotations

Tags: hibernate, collections

I have to map 
Private Map> variable ;
using annotations in Hibernate. I tried using @ElementCollection but its showing error

> "Could not determine type for: java.util.List"

.Please suggest something.

```
public class A{

    @Id
    @Column
    private int aid;

    @ElementCollection
    @Column
    private Map<String,List<String>> amap;

    //getters and setters
}
```

Comment: Please share some code in your question

Comment: This won't help us. Please share the part of the code that causes the error. Not as comment, but in your question